# Correct way to render entity fields?

Tags: 7, entities

According to [Rendering Drupal 7 fields (the right way)](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way), the correct way to render fields is with code similar to the following one.

```php
$node = node_load($nid);
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_name', $field[$delta]);
```

This is for rendering node fields.

I am using the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module which lets you create custom bundles in the predefined "paragraph" entity. I could use *entity.tpl.php* to override the output of Paragraph module fields.

I want to print my fields that are stored in the entity, but the above code won't work because it is for nodes.

What is the code for a generic entity's field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent to the sample code you posted from the article, but for an entity type other than node would be the following one.

```php
$entities = entity_load('ENTITY_TYPE_NAME', array($YOUR_ENTITY_ID));
$entity = $entities[$YOUR_ENTITY_ID];
$field = field_get_items('ENTITY_TYPE_NAME', $entity, 'field_name');
$output = field_view_value('ENTITY_TYPE_NAME', $entity, 'field_name', $field[$delta]);
```

If you're doing this in a template, the entity fields should have already been retrieved by `template_preprocess_entity()` and made available under the `$content` variable, so you shouldn't have to do all these steps in an overridden entity template.

Comment: Is there any way to use `$content` to just print the actual value of the field, as at the moment, it prints out the mark up and label. I know that I can make extra field templates to get rid of the mark up (and remove the label from the Druapl UI), but I'd rather just access the content of the field.

Comment: You ought to be able to access the entity via `$content['field_name']['#object']`, then use that with the last 2 lines of the above sample code to extract your $output value.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function for that: [`field_attach_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_view/7.x).

I had to use it to get a renderable array from Paragraph entities. You can render this array with `render()`.

```php
$paragraphEntity = entity_load("paragraphs_item",array($paragraph['value']));
$renderableParagraphBundle = field_attach_view(
  "paragraphs_item",
  $paragraphEntity[$paragraph['value']], "full",
  $GLOBALS['language']->language,
  array()
);

print render($renderableParagraphBundle);
```